# Is there a unique number/code/ID for every device that can be accessed through React Native/Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, unique

I am seeking to implement a login process where my React Native app will simply be able to check something intrinsically unique about a user's device to set up an account for them, or alternatively log them into a previously used account. This is simply for a game, where the only variable I am storing is total exp the user has accrued, so I wanted to bypass the need for a strict/secure login implementation.

Anyway, I just wanted to know if there is some functionality in React Native/Expo where I can retrieve some kind of unique number/code/ID associated with a user's device (either Android or iOS) that I can use for this process?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782429/how-to-get-device-id-in-react-native-android

Comment: You can use this, this is unique for each device, https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#fetching-tokens-for-push-notifications